# Meaning of "che ne so che me stai a di' la verità?"

Tags: meaning, regional, pronouns, particles

I have heard the following dialogue between a prisoner and a guard in a movie:

> – So’ ‘n regalo dei carabinieri, ‘sti lividi!
>   – Queste sono accuse gravi!
>   – Eh, come le botte che m’hanno dato!
>   – E io che ne so che me stai a di’ la verità?

The English subtitle says that the last sentence means "How do I know that is the truth?". How does it mean that? I am familiar with the usage of "ne" in Italian, but I am not sure if I understood it here. "Che ne so" = What do I know of this ?

Comment: I don’t know how the two sentences are related, anyway the second one is a colloquial/dialectal way to express the idea that you don’t know the truth about something.

Comment: Suppongo che le frasi siano prese da qui: https://www.manifestosardo.org/sulla-mia-pelle-un-film-necessario/ (film Sulla mia pelle) ma entrambe sono scritte in romanesco, non come invece sono presentate qui sopra

Comment: @JoeTaras you are right, the dialogue is from "Sulla mia pelle". I have copied it from the subtitles before and they are a little different from what is really said. I also had cut 2 lines to simplify my question. I have updated the dialogue text in my question. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Penso che il dialogo si capisca meglio nel link che ha messo @JoeTaras.

Comment: “Che ne so che me stai a dire la verità” is a much clearer sentence. “*How do I know that you are telling me the truth?”*

Comment: I still do not understand "che ne so che". I'd say "Come so che" instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Ne` is used in this context as "pronome personale" (personal pronoun). It means "di ciò" ("of this {topic/person/whatever}").

`Che ne so` is a very common spoken expression meaning `what/how would I know about {it/him/her}`. It can be just an observation/question, or it can have a slightly sarcastic/aggressive/explanatory/pitiful meaning (the tone changes the meaning).

If used as question, it is rarely just a question: it is usually a rhetorical question that implies something more. For example: `bel trucco magico, ma che ne so che non hai scambiato il mazzo di carte con uno differente?` means `nice magic trick, but how would I know that you didn't swap the deck of cards for a different one?` (implying that's exactly what you/the magician did).

In your case, `Che ne so che me stai a dire la verità?` means `how would I know that you're telling the truth?` implying that there is no way I can have a certainty.

`Come so che me stai a dire la verità?` would be correct also, but it's a real genuine question.

From the [Treccani encyclopedia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ne-o-ne_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/):

> – come pronome ➔personale, è usato al posto delle forme di ciò, da
>   ciò, di questo, da quello ecc.
>
> (example) Ne (= di ciò) parlerò ai nostri soci
>
> (example) Una volta dimostrato che io ho ragione, ne (= da ciò) segue che voi
>   avete torto
>
> spesso con valore di ➔partitivo
>
> (example) Vorrei una caramella all’anice: ce ne (= di queste) sono ancora?
>
> In alcuni casi ne è usato solo per intensificare l’azione espressa da
>   alcuni verbi intransitivi nelle costruzioni con i pronomi personali
>   atoni mi, ti, si, ci, vi
>
> (example) Me ne vado via  Se ne stava tranquillo a casa

---

Side note: in `che ne so che me stai a dire la verità?` the `me` should be instead the pronoun `mi` ("mi stai a dire" = "telling me"). If you found it like this, just know that it is a dialectal expression (pretty informal/spoken, also).

Comment: I would say that this "ne" is a pronoun, but not a personal pronoun. I really don't understand why Treccani says it's a personal pronoun.

Comment: @Charo I have wondered the same. It is confusing and misleading.

Comment: @amm0nium why "prendi me" instead of "prendimi" ?  IMHO direct object/indirect object/reflexive pronouns are an extensive topic which do not need to be covered here. I'd prefer to focus on the question.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista yeah i know it's a separate topic, i was just trying to enrich the side note... it's better if i remove it